# Including CSRF token in AJAX Post calls

Tags: aem

We are using POST AJAX calls to sling servlet using jQuery and these are giving 403 forbidden error due to missing CSRF token only when the user is logged in. For anonymous access, it works fine.
How can we include this CSRF header in the AJAX call ? 
At dispatcher, do we need to allow "/libs/granite/csrf/token.json" ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to allow `/libs/granite/csrf/token.json` as well as the `CSRF-Token` header in the dispatcher ([Refer dispatcher documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/security-checklist.html#par_title)).

For the CSRF token, if you are dependant on the `granite.jquery` clientlib, then it should be available by default. Else, you need to add `granite.csrf.standalone` dependency in your client library so as to enable the CSRF framework. More about this can be found [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/security/csrf-protection.html).

Comment: I am working on application that migrated from 6.1 to 6.3, where could I get /etc/keys/hmac binary, so that token is generated when making ajax calls and ajax calls go through. Thanks.